# Excel VBA simple code bug

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function in Excel that:

1. Iterates through each worksheet
2. Checks if the supplied string exists in the supplied cell
3. Adds a predetermined cell value to the return value if step 2 evaluates to True

I've been stepping through my function and am getting the correct values until the function has to add the 4th cell to my return value.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Thanks!

---

```
Function Revenue(row As Integer, col As Integer, str As String) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer

        For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count

            If Worksheets(i).Cells(row, col) = str Then

                Revenue = Revenue + Worksheets(i).Cells(21, 2) // Bug occurs on 4th iteration
                Debug.Print Revenue

            End If

        Next i


End Function
```

Comment: What error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: I bet it's `Overflow` as `Revenue` is an integer. Maybe someone is making too much money :-)

Comment: I'm not seeing an error, my code simply stops running and I get a #VALUE as a result. I don't think it's an overflow issue b/c it bugs out on the fourth iteration whether Revenue = 50,000 or 30,000. Is there a debug tool that I'm not using correctly? Thanks!

Comment: 32767 is the max limit for a signed integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to establish values for **row** and **col** prior to using them.

Comment: They are declared in the function signature. It's not in the code formatting block though.

Comment: Then check the values in Cells(21,2) for each worksheet to insure they are nice  numbers rather than Text.

Comment: They are always numbers, never text. I double checked.

Comment: Then change all **Integer** into **Double**  in the function header and Dims